# ECS Tasks Randomly Lose Access To RDS/Redis but not Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

So we've been battling an issue with our move to ECS from deploying directly on top of EC2, we have applications that may be deployed and running fine, but randomly one of the 4 tasks we have deployed running our web app will lose all access to RDS and Redis, it *appears* to always be both at the same time, our healthchecks fail, the task is terminated and restarted.

Sometimes not a huge deal outside of the fact that traffic is still being served to the failing node for a small period of time, which is annoying.

BUT sometimes we get a chain of failures, one time we had all 4 of our tasks fail at once! Ouch, took our app down.

So here are the symptoms that cause us to pause:

- A failure of a single node does not result in the other nodes failing, even though their loads increase by 33%, so we doubt it's a load issue
- Failures do not coincide with load
- Load is generally low on these servers to begin with
- The failing task can still report errors to Rollbar (and oh does it send a lot of logs), so we know the Task has network access
- The Tasks are given access via security groups
- Removing all doubt that it's the security group (eg: a 0.0.0.0/0 rule) did not appear to fix it
- Sometimes appears to happen shortly after deploy, but may be just us keeping a closer eye on things
- New instance generally comes up fine, so it isn't like the RDS/Redis services are messed up
- *Seems* to be RDS and Redis at the same time, hinting that we lose all traffic to AWS
- Using fargate awsvpc network configuration (Octopus Deploy default)
- We did *not* experience anything like this on a bare EC2 instance running the containers on system
- There seems to be no pattern, can happen randomly mid-day, randomly at night, sometimes one node, sometimes two, have had it take down 4 *once*.
- It *appears* to only affect our production environment (this is a weird one that makes us scratch our head since other evidence is that it isn't load related)
- Doesn't appear to affect our back-end workers, which are running the same image (just with a different config)

Is there known to be some kind of network reliability issue with this configuration? Is there a way to *immediately* stop sending traffic to a node with a failing health check without taking the node entirely offline? We're debating moving back to Elastic Beanstalk or deploying Docker Swarm/K3s because the service interruptions are rough.

Comment: "Is there known to be some kind of network reliability issue with this configuration?" Nope. I have lots of different deployments running on ECS Fargate, communicating with RDS and Redis (ElastiCache) without anything like this. My first thought is maybe you have a single subnet with a bad route table or someting, and when a task gets deployed there it fails. Since it only happens in one environment, I would be checking all the VPC settings in that environment.

Comment: "Is there a way to immediately stop sending traffic to a node with a failing health check without taking the node entirely offline?" You could try adding a docker health check that does some sort of RDS communication check, which would probably fail faster than the load balancer health check. However with Fargate, there is no way that I know of to keep the node around after health checks fail.

Comment: Do you happen to be mounting EFS volumes to those ECS tasks? There was a networking issue on ECS tasks caused by a specific EFS transit encryption configuration, that I'm not sure AWS ever fixed. Other than that, do you have ECS Container Insights enabled so you can monitor CPU/Memory and other status of the individual containers?

Comment: @MarkB We'll check our route table, we had been meaning to make some changes since ECS instances end up not having internet access unless given a public IP due to the route table config, but as far as we can tell that shouldn't be causing it -- unless the IP address is changing. We assumed a routing issue should present itself always, not randomly.

No EFS volumes on the ECS tasks.

Comment: If you have the ECS task deploying to multiple subnets, and one subnet is configured incorrectly, then the issue would only appear when ECS happened to randomly deploy a task to that misconfigured subnet. Your comment re: "unless the IP address is changing" is a bit concerning. The IP addresses of Fargate tasks will definitely change each time they are deployed. What are you doing that depends on IP addresses *not* changing?

Comment: @MarkB nope, IP address changes either during task run (not expecting that), or the DNS entry resolving to a different IP randomly (eg: from internal to external or vice-versa), it's the only thing that I could imagine would allow a task to run fine for anything from 15 minutes to 2 weeks, and randomly just have them lose network access to RDS/MemoryDB off and on.

Comment: I don't follow how the IP address of a running task suddenly changing (which doesn't happen by the way) would have any impact on that task being able to connect to other services (RDS/MemoryDB). Those two things should not be related, unless you are only enabling specific ECS task IPs in the RDS/MemoryDB security groups, which would be entirely wrong.

Comment: On the other hand, RDS/MemoryDB private IP addresses will change regularly. If that's a problem then you need to examine how your code is connecting to those and configure it to retry.

Comment: From what we can tell, it seems to be our ECS instances are holding onto the old DNS resolution from when the IP address changes, problem is it isn't our app stack, a failure results in a rebooted node and it continues to have the problem, it's like the VPC is caching the value.

Comment: We ruled out it being our app because when a failure happens ECS boots up a new task, and the new task continued to have network issues until 10-15 minutes later of constant reboots of some 8 tasks again and again. The issue exists outside of the container and seems to be a DNS one.

Comment: Actually last outage lasted almost exactly 40 minutes, so... that's interesting.

Comment: I think I would file a support ticket with AWS if I were you. I don't think anybody without full access to your AWS account is going to be able to help at this point.